# MYSQL Calculate total and average based on another column

Tags: mysql

How would I go about calculating the average and total Bonus from each City?

```
Example Input
Toronto 5
Toronto 8
New York 7
New York 3
London 10

Desired Output:
City      Avg      Total
Toronto   6.5      13
New York  5        10
London    10       10
```

Comment: This is really basic SQL that should be covered in most tutorials. SO is not a programming school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple group by statement:

```
SELECT City, AVG(Bonus) as `Avg`, SUM(Bonus) AS Total
FROM Cities
GROUP BY City
```

See example sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/096394/2) with your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT city, AVG(bonus), SUM(bonus) FROM city_bonus GROUP BY city
```

Working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37abd32/1)